# make_unique Too Few Arguments in Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){cout << "ctorA " << endl;}
    ~A(){cout << "dtorA " << endl;}
};

class X{
    A arr[10];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    { unique_ptr<X> upX = make_unique<X>(); }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Qt Creator underlines `std::make_unique` and when I hover over it with mouse, it tells me there are "Too few arguments".  Compiles and runs fine. No errors or warnings as far as I can tell.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in Creator or something?  Newest compiler gcc7.3.something and Qt10.something. Just got it today.

Comment: [Which version of Creator are you using?](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16186) And have you tried using the Clang code model? See Creators C++ settings. Can't test it here, because I don't have Clang installed.

Comment: I'm using QtCreator 4.5.  No I don't have Clang installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt Creator seems to have issues with c++14 syntax highlighting, as pointed out in many threads in Qt forums (e.g. [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53133/qt-creator-syntax-checking-c-14/4) and [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/78414/how-to-get-qt-creator-to-recognize-std-chrono_literals/9)).

The suggested solution is to enable the [Clang Code Model plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html) 
 which seems to solve the issue, although I noticed some problems with automatic code formatting (Ctrl-I) when using the single quotation mark as a digit separator. Also `#ifdef`'s are having [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18801) kind of issue (solved closing/reopening the file). I'm using Qt Creator 4.4.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.